# fetching results from database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I was trying to echo the row from mysql table inside a DIV but doesn't work, if I put:

```
     echo $row['test'];
```

inside `while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){ 
            }` it works perfect but I wanted it to show inside a DIV tag. I know I am missing something but don't what it is. Thanks for your help.

```
                            <?php
            $mydb = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM test  order by id limit 1 ";
            $result = $mydb->query($sql);
            if (!$result) {
                echo $mydb->error;
            }
            while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){ 
            }
            $mydb->close ();

            ?>
            <html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div><? echo $row['test'];?>
            </div>
```

Comment: I don't know if it is GLOBAL or not, the above code is all I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move your html and php code around. `$row` exists inside of the while loop and you have it outside the while loop.

```
<?php
        $mydb = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM test  order by id limit 1 ";
        $result = $mydb->query($sql);
        if (!$result) {
            echo $mydb->error;
        }
        ?>
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
            <?php while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){ ?>
                <div><?php echo $row['test'];?></div>
            <?php 
            }
            $mydb->close ();
            ?>
            </body>
        </html>
```

This will create a new div for each row retrieved from the database.

Answer (score 0):

you are closing connection before fetching

```
       $mydb->close ();
```

remove that line and put it in the end of your code.

and put your html code inside the while loop.

```
 <?php
     $mydb = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM test  order by id limit 1 ";
     $result = $mydb->query($sql);
  if (!$result) {
  echo $mydb->error;
 }
 ?> 
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div>
 <?php
 while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
 echo $row['test'];
 }
 $mydb->close ();
 ?>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to put the `$row['test']` inside of your `while` block again, and move your HTML around.

```
<?php
$mydb = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test  order by id limit 1 ";
$result = $mydb->query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    echo $mydb->error;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<?php
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
    echo $row['test'];
}
$mydb->close ();
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```